# Given these results, how would these teams be ranked in the UEFA European Championship?

Tags: football, tie-breaker, uefa, euro, championship

Hypothetically, let's say England, Portugal, Croatia and Israel are drawn together for the UEFA Euro 2024 tournament. Let's also assume that the teams have a European Qualification Ranking of 5, 8, 6 and 41 respectively and that all 4 teams have exactly the same discipline.

The first three teams all draw against each but register identical wins against Israel leaving a table as follows:

[image: Group Table]

Two of the three teams (England and Portugal) face off in their final group game. Per UEFA tiebreaking rules a penalty shootout should occur - let's say that Portugal win which means that they rank above England.

However, this is where I'm stuck. How would Croatia get ranked here?
Portugal (8) should go beneath Croatia (6) BUT England (5) would go above Croatia but that wouldn't be correct as they lost to Portugal in their penalty shootout.

I know this is very unlikely scenario but what should be done here?
Looking at [UEFA Euro 2024 Wikipedia page - Tiebreakers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFA_Euro_2024#Tiebreakers) it does say for penalties that this won't be used if more than 2 teams have the same number of points so perhaps this is my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems, you're correct.

Penalty shootout can't be used when three teams have the same number of points. So, the criterion number 7 in [Tieabreakers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFA_Euro_2024#Tiebreakers) is not applicable here.

If the teams are also tied on disciplinary points the last criterion will apply:

> Higher position in the European Qualifiers overall ranking, unless the comparison involves hosts Germany, in which case a drawing of lots will take place.

England and Croatia will be ranked first and second, respectively. Portugal will take the third place with high chances to also advance to the knockout phase based on ranking of third-placed teams.